# Spring MVC Static Resources Versioning with Thymeleaf and Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc, webpack, thymeleaf

I have single page application with spring mvc, thymeleaf on the backend side and with Angular and webpack on the frontend side. Spring MVC is responsible for serving versioned static resources together with thymeleaf, actually following configurations below are used for this:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(cacheControlMaxAge, SECONDS).noTransform().mustRevalidate())
                .resourceChain(false)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
                .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());
    }
```

Additionally following filter `ResourceUrlEncodingFilter` is used for encoding resources URLs.

On the frontend side in `index.html` static resources are included in following way:

```
th:src="@{/resources/static/js/some.js}"
th:src="@{/resources/static/css/some.css}"
th:src="@{/resources/static/img/some.img}"
```

And everything works fine for such hardcoded links in `index.html`, namely in network tab of the browser I can see requests with versioned names for my static resources.

**But the issue is in the following:** I additionally use webpack to build  angular application. Webpack can dynamically include scripts into `index.html` based on used imports in frontend codebase. So, for such cases I cannot manually wrap script links with thymeleaf tags.

Could you please advice how it can be managed for such case, what is the best practices for this?